# Is there a way to change how tab characters are rendered in a browser?

Tags: browser, tabs, code-formatting

Specifically in Firefox.  We look at code in the browser often, and I am wondering if we could configure the browser so that tab characters show up as 4 spaces wide, instead of the default 8 spaces.

Edit: no responses yet.  So I assume this is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Not really the answer you are looking for but maybe you could replace the tab characters with the appropriate amount of spaces and use the "pre" tag?

It is definitely worth looking at the html source to see how sites like stackoverflow.com deal with displaying source code.